# High CPU Usage and Synchronous XMLHttpRequest Warning With setInterval() and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to update a shell command output each second using AJAX.

However, Chrome CPU usage is too high and output update seems to be updating so fast ( not one second )

Here is the HTML Document:

```
    <script src='jquery-2.2.4.js'></script>
    <script>

        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("body").html(data);
                },
                async: true
            });
        }, 1000);

    </script>
</body>
```

And here is the shell command I'm actually using:

`system("dir C:");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The AJAX request URL was the same URL I requested from which caused an infinite recursive loop.

So what I did is to request it from another PHP page which contains the data I actually need.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use a setTimeout which will be called after every successful ajax completion.

You could setup also an error handler in the $.ajax because a network fail might happen and call there again the setTimeout(function(){myajaxfunction();},1000);

```
  var myajaxfunction = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $("body").html(data);
                setTimeout(function(){myajaxfunction()},1000);
            },
            async: true
        });
    };
    myajaxfunction();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however it seems that the AJAX request still runs in infinite loop

Comment: Yes it will never stop, but it will fire every 1 second +plus the time that the request to the server takes to respond, and after it responds it will fire again. The problem with the setInterval as it was before,  is that it will fire every 1 second even if the ajax request has not finished yet . Is there any other condition that you need to apply?

Comment: It was running so fast which caused High CPU usage. I actually figured it out and It a was silly mistake. The actual page was requesting itself with caused a recursive loop, thank you.